# Android HttpsURLConnection giving SSLHandshakeException after disabling cipher suites in backend

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpurlconnection

Our backend is Azure App Service (Linux) that with default settings supports the following cipher suite:

> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

When I disable all ciphers but the two first ones all http connections to the backend fail with exception

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed

We have the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

SSLSocketFactory factory = connection.getSSLSocketFactory()
String[] cipherSuites = factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
for (String suite : cipherSuites) {
    System.out.println(suite);
}

connection.connect();
```

The SSLSocketFactory was added just to print the supported cipher suites. The output is:

> TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
> TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
> TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV

So at least the first cipher, e.g. TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 seems to be supported by both.

The app for various historical reasons have sdk 28 as minimum and target sdk

```
minSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Why is the handshake not finding a common cipher?

Comment: Have you tried using OkHttp, as it has [better HTTPS support](https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/https/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I disable all ciphers but the two first ones all http connections to the backend fail with exception

This means that the following ciphers are left:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

Both require ECDSA authentication, which means they need an ECC certificate. Probably you only have a RSA certificate though, which means that the server does not support any ciphers which can work together with the  certificate used by the server.

Comment: Perfect. When I also added TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 it works.